# How to add REST support in existing server ?

Tags: wcf

I wrote some WCF server that support SOAP. 
Now, i need to add some new request ... to add support in REST in some of the method that are supported SOAP.

I don't know how to do it. 
Actually one of those method need to change to support REST.

How to do it ?

Comment: Did you read the developer center [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529) yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add WebHttpBinding and a new service contract interface with the relevant REST methods annotated with UriTemplate. Encapsulate your business logic in a class that is used by soap service class and the rest service class both.